# I am getting an resize_tensor_input failed to reshape error while using tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, tensorflow-lite, bert-language-model

So I have the model and everything working, when i pass 1 input to a tflite model. But for batch inference, I need to pass 1000 values for this i am resizing the tensor input size but i get the following error:

```
tensorflow/lite/kernels/reshape.cc:69 num_input_elements != num_output_elements (100000 != 100)Node number 6 (RESHAPE) failed to invoke.
```

Code I am using is:

```
interpreter.resize_tensor_input(input_details[0]['index'], [1, 1000, 100])
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data10)
interpreter.invoke()
```

on last line it gives me this error.

Comment: Please make sure that your TFLite model can handle the arbitrary batch size. If not, please consider conducting TFLite conversion again with a TF model with dynamic dimension at the input batch size.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort out the above problem by changing the np.expands line.

Initially I was using:

input_data10 = np.expand_dims(input_text[1:1001], axis=0)

which I changed to
input_data10 = np.expand_dims(input_text[1:1001], axis=1)

so by changing the axis, it worked for me.